# Why won't the routing work in this code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

This is just a little project to learn [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), and I'm having trouble getting the routing to work. According to every tutorial I've looked over what I have here should work, but it doesn't, unfortunately. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me find my problem and help me fix it.

Here is my index:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="danApp">
        <head>
            <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="Scripts/test.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div ng-view></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

#### View 1

```html
<h1>View 1</h1>
<br><br><br><br>
<div>
   <input type="text" ng-model="nameText" >
      <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="things in info | filter: nameText | orderBy:'name'">
            Name: {{ things.name }} <br> Age: {{ things.age }} <br>
            City: {{ things.city }}
            <br>
         </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

#### View 2

```html
<h1>View 2</h1>
<br><br><br><br>
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="nameText" >
      <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="stuff in parents | filter: nameText | orderBy:'name'">
            Name: {{ stuff.name }} <br> Age: {{ stuff.age }} <br>
            City: {{ stuff.city }}
            <br>
         </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

And, finally, my *module*, *controllers*, and *routing code*

```js
"use strict";

 var danApp = angular.module('danApp', []);
               
 danApp.controller("danCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.info = [
        {name: 'Daniel', age: '22', city: 'Clarksville'},
        {name: 'Derek', age: '19', city: 'Jacksonville'},
        {name: 'Emily', age: '18', city: 'Erin'},
        {name: 'Denise', age: '27', city: 'Phoenix'}, 
    ];
 });
               
               
 danApp.controller("danCtrl2", function($scope) {
   $scope.parents = [
      {name: 'Lathan', age: '54', city: 'Stewart'},
      {name: 'Candy', age: '54', city: 'Stewart'},
      {name: 'Christine', age: '43', city: 'Erin'}
   ];
 });           
               
               
danApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
      .when('/',
      {
         controller: 'danCtrl',
         templateUrl: 'views/view1.html'
      })
      .when('/view2',
      {
         controller: 'danCtrl2',
         templateUrl: 'views/view2.html'
      })
      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});
```

Comment: Is it just me or is there no `ng-controller` in your code?

Comment: Check the console, are you getting an errors? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @Fuzzyma. There is no ng-controller in the code, but it's not required when using routing. It looks to be a simple issue of not including angular-routing

Comment: as wayne stated just before, you need to add `<script src="Scripts/angular-route.js">` like here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.
You will also have to add it in your modules : `angular.module('danApp', ['ngRoute']);`

Comment: @WayneEllery This was the problem. Thank you very much. I thought the first angular.min.js file was all that I needed. I will look into other files for different features. Thanks again.

Comment: Please select my answer as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you need to include the `angular-route.js` or `angular-route.min.js` script which can be downloaded from the [Angular website](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.12/). In index.html add the script:

```
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

The module then needs to be added to your module:

```
var danApp = angular.module('danApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kxuRk9HMgtEoFpipZeH1?p=preview)